# Stud hole exception to staples with NM cable

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, nec

In my reading of 334.30, am I allowed to omit staples near a junction box if NM cable is supported by a hole in the stud within 18" (or 12")?

Here is an image; can I get away with this or do I need a staple between each of the junction box entry clamps and the stud hole?

https://i.ibb.co/YfjgT8Z/Stud-Support.jpg

Comment: Do not know, but I think I have read on here cables need support(stables) within a few inches of a box.  As you diagram it, the stud hole is pass the limit(I think it is less than 8 inches).  Will need the code experts to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need at least one securement other than the hole through the stud: "Horizontal Runs Through Holes and Notches.: ...and the nonmetallic-sheathed cable is securely fastened in place by an approved means within 300 mm (12 in.) of each box..."

Since you can't make a sharp 90 degree bend in the NM, I'm not sure where you would put your securement for the lower right box in your diagram.

> Recent Code Language, maybe 2017?:
>
> 334.30 Securing and Supporting.
>
> Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be supported and secured by staples;
> cable ties listed and identified for securement and support; or
> straps, hangers, or similar fittings designed and installed so as not
> to damage the cable, at intervals not exceeding 1.4 m (41/2 ft) and
> within 300 mm (12 in.) of every cable entry into enclosures such as
> outlet boxes, junction boxes, cabinets, or fittings. Flat cables shall
> not be stapled on edge.
>
> Sections of cable protected from physical damage by raceway shall not
> be required to be secured within the raceway.

> (A) Horizontal Runs Through Holes and Notches.
>
> In other than vertical runs, cables installed in accordance with 300.4 shall be
> considered to be supported and secured where such support does not
> exceed 1.4-m (41/2-ft) intervals and the nonmetallic-sheathed cable is
> securely fastened in place by an approved means within 300 mm (12 in.)
> of each box, cabinet, conduit body, or other nonmetallic-sheathed
> cable termination.
>
> ```
> Informational Note: See 314.17(C) for support where nonmetallic boxes are used.
> ```
>
> (B) Unsupported Cables.
>
> Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>
> (1) Is fished between access points through concealed spaces in finished buildings or structures and supporting is impracticable.
>
> (2) Is not more than 1.4 m (41/2 ft) from the last point of cable support to the point of connection to a luminaire or other piece
> of electrical equipment and the cable and point of connection are
> within an accessible ceiling in one-, two-, or multifamily dwellings.
>
> (C) Wiring Device Without a Separate Outlet Box.
>
> A wiring device identified for the use, without a separate outlet box, and
> incorporating an integral cable clamp shall be permitted where the
> cable is secured in place at intervals not exceeding 1.4 m (41/2 ft)
> and within 300 mm (12 in.) from the wiring device wall opening, and
> there shall be at least a 300 mm (12 in.) loop of unbroken cable or
> 150 mm (6 in.) of a cable end available on the interior side of the
> finished wall to permit replacement.

Comment: Thanks Armand, I was thinking of dropping it down below the box and then bending it up along the stud with a 3" radius before it gets stapled and then enters the bottom of the box.   Seems a bit silly, but if that's what is required then that's what I'll do.